# Matrix of rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

I am haunted by a question. Consider a vector  $v=\begin{bmatrix} a\\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix}$ is firstly multiplied by $R_1= \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta_1) &-\sin(\theta_1)&0\\ \sin(\theta_1) &\cos(\theta_1)&0 \\ 0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$ and secondly is rotated along rotated axe $x$ by $R_2= \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&\cos(\theta_2) &-\sin(\theta_2)\\0& \sin(\theta_2) &\cos(\theta_2)\end{bmatrix}$ and finally is rotated along rotated axe $y$ by $R_3= \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta_3)&0 &-\sin(\theta_3)\\0&1&0\\ \sin(\theta_3)&0 &\cos(\theta_3)\end{bmatrix}$. At last, $v$ is transformed into new position $v'=\begin{bmatrix} a'\\ b' \\ c' \end{bmatrix}$. We could express the angles of rotation relative to the 3 axis of inertial reference by projecting the original vector and transformed vector to $XOY$,$ZOY$ and $XOZ$. But if we do not use this vector, imagining that at the origin of the inertial reference there is a small ball or just a point which experiences these three rotations one by one, how could we give or simplify an expression of angles of rotation relative to the three inertial reference axis which the ball or point experiences. I find out a solution too complex and looks like wrong.

Could you give me a hint or guide to treat this haunting (just for me) question. Thank you very much for taking a look.

Comment: What is "inertial reference"? You mean Cartesian coordinate axes, right?

Comment: Yes, here is my strange solution, thank you for criticizing.

Comment: $\theta_1\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\0 \\1\end{bmatrix}+\theta_2 R_1 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\\0\end{bmatrix}+\theta_3 R_2 R_1 \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\1 \\0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I am not criticising, just clarifying. You know the matrices representing the rotation. Just multiply them in the correct order to get a matrix which will give the resultant rotation. What is the problem? The answer should be $R_3 R_2 R_1 v$.

Comment: Exactly, the final position of the vector is $R_3 R_2 R_1 v$. What haunted me is the rotation angles of $v$ about the Cartesian coordinate axes, but not about rotated x and rotated y.

Comment: $\theta_1\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\0 \\1\end{bmatrix}.$ Note multiplying by $\theta_1$ will only make it $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\0 \\\theta_1\end{bmatrix}$ which is just stretching the vector, not rotating it.

Comment: Take the final vector and use the "cosine formula" for angle between two vectors to find the angle between the resultant and the coordinate axes.

Comment: I am sorry for not clarifying. The sum of the vectors represents the three rotation angles about axes of Cartesian coordinate.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It helps a lot :)

Comment: It might help to read about Euler angles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles